# Extract data from PDF document

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-scraping

I have a PDF document.

It contains data in tabular format. I want to extract the data into a comma delimited text file using the comma as column delimiters.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried anything like exploring some APIs?

Comment: Hello. Like which API?. I am eager to learn how to use it.

Comment: You can try Apache Tika. Apache Tika is basically a toolkit that extracts data from many types of documents, including PDFs. Or you can explore more like itextpdf, etc.

Comment: Let me try itextpdf.

Comment: You may try Algodocs: https://algodocs.com. It works perfectly for PDFs with tables that even span to hundreds of pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard PDFs do not provide any hints about the *semantics* of what they draw on a page: the only distinction that the syntax provides is the distinctions between vector elements (lines, fills,...), images and text.

Whether any character is part of a table or part of a line or just a lonely, single character within an otherwise empty area is not easy to recognize programmatically by parsing the PDF source code.

For a background about why the ***PDF file format should never, ever be thought of as suitable for hosting extractable, structured data***, see this article:

> **[Why Updating Dollars for Docs Was So Difficult](http://www.propublica.org/nerds/item/heart-of-nerd-darkness-why-dollars-for-docs-was-so-difficult)** (ProPublica-Website)

Having said the above now let me add this:

- For an amazing open source family of tools that gets better and better from week to week for extracting tabular data from PDFs (unless they are scanned pages) -- ***contradicting what I said in my introductionary paragraphs***! -- check out ***[TabulaPDF](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula)***. See these links:

  - **[Introducing Tabula: Upload a PDF, get back tabular CSV data. Poof!](https://source.opennews.org/en-US/articles/introducing-tabula/)**
  - **[Tabula-Extractor: A Command Line Interface to Tabula](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-extractor)**
  - **[Tabula source code repository](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula)**
  - **[Tabula API (upcoming, not ready yet)](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-api)**

Tabula is written in Ruby.

---

### Update

Here is an ASCiinema screencast (which you also can **[download](https://asciinema.org/a/22761.json)** and re-play locally in your Linux/MacOSX/Unix terminal with the help of the `asciinema` command line tool), starring `tabula-extractor`:

[image: asciicast]